# Set requirements for get request parameters in symfony's controller

Tags: php, symfony

I have a controller which handles a GET request. I need to set requirement parameters for GET request, e.g.: 'http://localhost/site/main?id=10&sort=asc

My controller class

```
class IndexController extends Controller {
`   /**
     * @Route
     * (
     *     "/site/main", 
     *     name="main"
     * )
     *
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function mainAction(Request $request) 
    {
        return new Response('', 200);
    }
}
```

How could I do that?

UPD: I need to set requirement for URL parameters like
id: "\d+",
sort: "\w+"
Etc.
The same as symfony allows to do with POST request.

Comment: Did you read up on this page? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

Comment: Take a look at the docs for routing, specifically for requirements: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-requirements

Comment: @EmanuelOster Couldn't find any working solution for my case. If you did, please show the solution.

Comment: You can't add requirements for the query-part of the request. You'll need to validate those inside the controller manually.

Comment: @Yoshi alright, if so, then... thank you

Comment: Maybe this [*"Completely Customized Route Matching with Conditions"*](https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#completely-customized-route-matching-with-conditions) would work, though I haven't used it.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the requirements in the "@Route" annotation like this:

```
class IndexController extends Controller {

`   /**
     * @Route
     * (
     *     "/site/main", 
     *     name="main",
     *     requirements={
     *     "id": "\d+",
     *     "sort": "\w+"
     * })
     * )
     *
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function mainAction(Request $request) 
    {
        return new Response('', 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. These "requirements" are for parameters in the path of the route (e.g. if the route has a path like "/site/main/{id}/{sort}"), not for parameters in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

@Method is what you need http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#route-method

If you try to use this route with POST, you will have 404

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your question well.
However, if what you need is to set up a filter mechanism for the GET method parameters as it is already available for the URL using route requirements, I think there is no ready to use tools for this in the Route component, as commented [@Yoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697154/yoshi).

I had to do this kind of work myself and used this. I hope it helps you too

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    // Parameter names used in the current request
    $current_request_params=array_keys($request->query->all());

     // $ALLOWED_INDEX_PARAMS should be declared as Class static property array and hold names of the query parameters you want to allow for this method/action
    $unallowed_request_params=array_diff($current_request_params,PersonController::$ALLOWED_INDEX_PARAMS);

    if (!empty($unallowed_request_params))
    {
        $result=array("error"=>sprintf("Unknown parameters: %s. PLease check the API documentation for more details.",implode($unallowed_request_params,", ")));

        $jsonRsp=$this->get("serializer")->serialize($result,"json");

        return new Response($jsonRsp,Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST,array("Content-Type"=>"application/json"));
    }
    // We are sure all parameters are correct, process the query job ..
}
```